# How to make a trigger work after a certain UPDATE

Tags: oracle, trigger

I would like to know if it's possible to create a trigger on Oracle that is invoked only when a certain UPDATE is done. For example:

```
UPDATE colors
SET tastes_good = y
WHERE color_name = 'Apple';
```

should call the trigger, while

```
UPDATE colors
SET tastes_good = n
WHERE color_name = 'Apple';
```

should not.

Comment: It's easy, you can just check :new.column_name for whatever takes your fancy. The before/after update trigger will always fire, but you can do/not do stuff depending on the values and your logic

Comment: Newer versions of Oracle have new tricks: `when` clause and `update of <column_list>` clause which can be used to further restrict when your trigger will be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will suit your needs:

```
create or replace trigger colors_utrig
after update on colors
for each row
begin
  if :new.tastes_good = 'y'
    then
      -- put your code here
      NULL;
  end if;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `when` clause as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER color_tastes_good_y
  BEFORE UPDATE ON colors
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (NEW.tastes_good = 'y')
BEGIN
  NULL; -- replace with your logic
END;
/
```

Comment: How did I not know about the `WHEN` clause?! Learn something new every day...

Comment: It gets even better: you can also do `BEFORE UPDATE OF <col1>,<col2>,... ON <table>`. And I edited your answer to remove the `REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW` which is redundant.